# Updating columns within a Cursor For Loop

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm running a CURSOR FOR LOOP, and among the things I'm trying to do, is to update a column for each record, with the day on which the loop was run. I've included the following statement within the loop

```
UPDATE SALES_TABLE
SET SETTLEMENTDATE = SYSDATE
WHERE RECEIPTNO= R1.RECEIPTNO;
```

In this case, RECEIPTNO is a PK, if that makes any difference. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? The SETTLEMENTDATE column just remains NULL.

UPDATED WITH GREATER FOR LOOP VISIBILITY

```
FOR R1 IN c_dbfData LOOP

...

UPDATE SALES_TABLE
SET SETTLED = 'Y'
WHERE RECEIPTNO = R1.RECEIPTNO;

UPDATE SALES_TABLE
SET SETTLEMENTDATE = SYSDATE
WHERE RECEIPTNO= R1.RECEIPTNO;

END LOOP;
```

All I've excluded with the ellipsis is just writing to a file, which works fine.

Comment: Could you post the complete FOR loop? How do you check your data? Have you COMMITted your changes?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Updated, but there wasn't much you weren't already seeing. Unfamiliar with COMMIT - is that what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I fail to see what is the problem/question.

Comment: @user272735 I am trying to update the SETTLEMENTDATE column in this table, but it doesn't update, remains as NULL.

Comment: @user3544027 Unless you COMMIT your transaction, other sessions won't be able to see it. Did you check your data from the same session where you ran your FOR loop? Or from a different session?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt This is a standalone procedure. I'm running it, then once its finished running, I'm doing a SELECT * on the table. Still not updating. Just added COMMIT WORK; to the end, still not updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you modify your code as follows:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Entering update loop');

DECLARE
  nRows_read  NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR R1 IN c_dbfData LOOP
    nRows_read := nRows_read + 1;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('In loop, R1.RECEIPTNO=' || R1.RECEIPTNO);

    BEGIN
       ...  -- put your file logic here
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error in file logic: SQLCODE=' || SQLCODE ||
                           '  SQLERRM=' || SQLERRM);
        RAISE;
    END;

    BEGIN
      UPDATE SALES_TABLE
        SET SETTLED = 'Y'
        WHERE RECEIPTNO = R1.RECEIPTNO;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  First update successful for RECEIPTNO=' ||
                           R1.RECEIPTNO ||  
                           ', ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows updated');
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error in first UPDATE for RECEIPTNO=' ||
                             R1.RECEIPTNO || ': SQLCODE=' || SQLCODE ||
                             '  SQLERRM=' || SQLERRM);
        RAISE;
    END;

    BEGIN
      UPDATE SALES_TABLE
        SET SETTLEMENTDATE = SYSDATE
        WHERE RECEIPTNO= R1.RECEIPTNO;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  Second update successful for RECEIPTNO=' ||
                           R1.RECEIPTNO ||  
                           ', ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows updated');
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error in second UPDATE for RECEIPTNO=' ||
                             R1.RECEIPTNO || ': SQLCODE=' || SQLCODE ||
                             '  SQLERRM=' || SQLERRM);
        RAISE;
    END;
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Update loop complete, ' || nRows_read || ' rows read');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error caught in outer handler after ' || nRows_read ||
                         'rows: SQLCODE=' || SQLCODE ||
                         '  SQLERRM=' || SQLERRM');
    RAISE;
END;
```

Then examine the DBMS_OUTPUT from the above. You should ideally see a list of the RECEIPTNO's which were processed, and a line for each update noting how many rows were altered by the update.

Alternatively, if you're using a tool such as PL/SQL Developer which provides easy access to the Oracle PL/SQL debugger you could leave out the internal PUT_LINE's and just set breakpoints on the PUT_LINE calls in the EXCEPTION blocks and then run your procedure under the debugger to see if it hits either of the breakpoints.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I it's not a problem with the commit logic, something must be off with the where clause (RECEIPTNO=R1.RECEIPTNO). Either R1.RECEIPTNO does not contain the values you would expect or the table sales_table is not populated as you expect.

Generally speaking:
- it would be twice as fast, to combine the two update sin your example
- even faster if you can update in a single statement without the procedural loop